# Java ZonedDateTime.format issue

Tags: java, zoneddatetime, datetimeformatter

Running into `ZonedDateTime` formatting issue. It formats end of December, 2020 dates as 2021 dates.
Java snippet

```java
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0), ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
z1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("YYYY-MM-dd"))
// yields "2021-12-31"
```

Same goes for December 28th, 29th, 30th. Same result for different time-zones.
Repeats for December 30 2019 (formats as 2020-12-30).

Original Clojure snippet

```clj
(let [zdt (ZonedDateTime/of (LocalDateTime/of 2020 12 31 0 0) (ZoneId/of "America/New_York"))
      f (DateTimeFormatter/ofPattern "YYYY-MM-dd")]
  (.format zdt f))
; => "2021-12-31"
```

I am able to reproduce on:

- MacOS HotSpot Java 10 (java version "10.0.2" 2018-07-17)
- OpenJDK version "11.0.9.1" 2020-11-04

If you're OK with Lisps – you can see it for yourself in a cloud REPL [here](https://repl.it/@IvanFedorov1/FruitfulOurCustomization#main.clj)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the pattern string to `yyyy-MM-dd`.
Refer to the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) for class `DateTimeFormatter` to understand the difference between `YYYY` and `yyyy`.

```java
ZonedDateTime z1 = ZonedDateTime.of(LocalDateTime.of(2020, 12, 31, 0, 0), ZoneId.of("America/New_York"));
System.out.println(z1.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")));
```

Result:

```
2020-12-31
```

Comment: yes, that works

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found it. It’s just my formatting mistake.

- Y is for week-based-year
- y is for era year
- u is for just year

So use `"uuuu-MM-dd"` and it all works

Comment: Or, much more simply, `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_LOCAL_DATE`.